# I used subprocess.popen in GUI(pysimplegui) python script it is working fine on pycharm and when I make its exe file is making its clone

Tags: python-3.x, webdriver, subprocess, pysimplegui, auto-py-to-exe

I used subprocess.popen (for open webdriver) in GUI(pysimplegui) python script, it is working fine on pycharm and when I make its exe file is making its clone while clicking on a specific button[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDyIW.png)

```
elif event == 'web':
    subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "sele.py"])
```

please help me on this how to handle this thing or how to create subprocess correctly
the reason why I am not making a function for it is because if I will do this my button will stuck until the whole function is done
thanks

I try different type of subprocess and multithreading but nothing works for me

Comment: Subprocess makes a fork, so if you don't have your "main" program in a function it will create another copy of your window when the subprocess starts.  The PySimpleGUI Exec APIs may be of help and also the threading calls within PySimpleGUI (e.g. window.start_thread is good for long operations).

Comment: Thank you very much man you save my day.....
Kindly suggest me a tutorial or documentary where I can learn all major and basic concepts of PySimpleGui.

Comment: https://www.PySimpleGUI.org is the main documentation that has a Cookbook along with the main documentation and the call reference.  https://eCookbook.PySimpleGUI.org is an interactive cookbook (try it!  It's fun).  https://Udemy.PySimpleGUI.org is the official PySimpleGUI course on Udemy.  The top of the documentation always has a coupon and link to get a discount.  Asking questions on the project's github https://Issues.PySimpleGUI.org will get you answers from the developers directly.  Be sure to get the Demo Program Launcher.  The demo mentions the need for this function.